# JQuery date picker does not firing in ajax page using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here I have using datepicker from JQueryUI
in my public/javascript folder as effects,prototype,control,dragdrop js files.
in my public folder contains jqueryui development buddle. (css,js,development-bundle)

in layout/application.rhtml

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <%=javascript_include_tag :defaults%>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/jquery-ui/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css' %>
<%=javascript_include_tag "/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"%>
<%=javascript_include_tag "/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"%>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
            $j( '#date' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
             });
    </script>
```

in home/index.rhtml

```
<%title "Home"%>
<%=link_to "Add Details" ,:action=>"add"%>
<%=link_to_remote "Ajax Add Details", :update=>"add" , :url=>{ :action=>"add" }%>
<div id='add' />
```

in  home/add.rhtml

```
<%title "Add details"%>
<%form_tag :action=>"create" do%>
    Name : <%=text_field_tag "name" ,"",:size=>15%>
    DOB  : <%=text_field_tag "dob","",:id=>"date"%>
    <%=submit_tag "Save"%>
<%end%>
```

the datepicker works when I run home/add.rhtml directly but
the datepicker not work when i run ajax page home/index.rhtml

Any solutions for that,????

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic behaviour in a web page. You're affecting a behaviour on an element which is absent. You could simply get the best of callbacks methods:

You could do the following:

```
function format_date() {
   var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
   $j( '#date' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
};

<%=link_to_remote "Ajax Add Details", :update=>"add" , :url=>{ :action=>"add" }, :success =>"format_date()"%>
```

This will work because the element exists when you trigger the function.

For culture's sake, have a look at jQuery's live() function.